# Python HDFS file open using subprocess hdfs "cat: Illegal file pattern: Illegal character range near index 11"

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs, cat

I am trying to load informatica log files which are stored on a Hadoop cluster in HDFS. I am using subprocess in Python to do so, but believe that I am getting an error because of the filename and I'm not sure how to workaround it.

The error I get is "cat: Illegal file pattern: Illegal character range near index 11"

My code is:

```
input = subprocess.Popen(["hadoop", "fs", "-cat", '/corp_staffs/IT/IICOE/process/infa_stats/WorkflowLogs/infra.[08-04-2015-(15_19)].1438719569664.log'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

# read the lines into an array
for line in input.stdout:
        print line
```

I could rename every file to avoid cat thinking there's a regex in the filename but I'd rather not. Is there a way to workaround this?

Comment: I'm guessing it's not actually a regex at all but a glob-style pattern; regexes aren't a good choice for this use case (for instance, in a regex, `.` is a single-character wildcard; folks use periods in filenames all the time).

Comment: For a glob-style pattern, you only need to escape brackets, asterisks and question marks.

Comment: Also, there are examples of folks using `hadoop fs -cat` with strings like `output/*`; that doesn't make sense as a regex, but makes perfect sense as a glob pattern.

Comment: I had never heard of a glob style pattern until now. Thank you!

Comment: "A glob-style pattern" is what, f'rinstance, `*.txt` is; as a regex, that outright fails to parse, since `*` in regex refers to the character before it, so can't legally be a first character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
quotechars=re.compile('|'.join(re.escape(s) for s in r'\[]()*?'))
def quote_name(filename):
    return re.sub(quotechars, r'\\\g<0>', filename)

input = subprocess.Popen(
    [
        "hadoop", "fs", "-cat",
        quote_name('/corp_staffs/IT/IICOE/process/infa_stats/WorkflowLogs/infra.[08-04-2015-(15_19)].1438719569664.log')
    ], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```